# Changing the UIView Orientation Programmatically without shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I am looking to change the orientation of an UIView without using the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation method. I would like to know if the is a method I can call that will set the orientation in a similar matter. Can this be done or do I have to programmatically transform all the objects in the form?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not use a view controller then you have to manually apply the transform to the view based on the device orientation.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you have to do this yourself with affine transformations:

```
    self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / 2);
```